# BigQuery, transform INTEGER variable to DATE

Tags: sql, date, casting, integer, google-bigquery

I have a dataset with a date variable coded as `NUMERIC`.

e.g. "01/03/2005" appears as "1032005"

I want to transform the variable to `STRING`, pad it with leading zeroes, and then transform in to a `DATE` format. In BigQuery casting appears not to be allowed, so I create a new variable ad hoc, but I am unable to report there the original values.

How should I do it?

Comment: Is the format DDMMYYYY or MMDDYYYY ?  In other words, does 103 equal January 3 or March 1 ?

Comment: The date Is March 1st, European style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format as a string and then parse as a date:

```
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%d%m%Y', FORMAT('%08d', int_date))
FROM (SELECT 1032005 AS int_date)
```

This gives:

```
2005-03-01
```

Comment: I don't know what "does not work" means in this context.

Comment: You could create a new table, then copy it over the old one. In your question, though, you asked about how to transform an integer to a date, not how to update a table with a new column or whatever the actual goal is.

Comment: I used the code provided by Elliott thus:


`UPDATE Table
SET new_var = PARSE_DATE('%d%m%Y', FORMAT('%08d', old_var))
WHERE TRUE`

This took me more than it should have.